# Difficulty with running an application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making a simple android application with a button and a EditText.

In eclipse, I have written this activity_main.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and in the string.xml file, I have written the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">v1</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a Message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

The code as such is not showing any error, but when I try to run the code, It throws error.

What should I do ?

Comment: When you get an error, learn to read the logcat. Without this information, you'r blind and don't know the nature of the problem you are facing. You need to post the logcat here to allow people to help you.

Comment: Can you post Your Logcat Errors

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error is thrown? I´m not sure, but here

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

you dont use `android:id` . If you dont have `id` for button, you can´t use it in java code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the id for the button which you will be using in java code.

```
<Button 
    android:id="@id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```